# Parallel BZip2 Compression

Tags: java, parallel-processing, compression, bzip2, apache-commons-compress

i'm using [Apache Commons Compress](http://commons.apache.org/compress/index.html) for Java to compress **multiple** log files to a **single** `tar.bz2` archive.

However, it takes really long (> 12 hours) to compress, because i compress around 20GB of files a day.

As this library compresses files mono-threaded, i'd like to know if there is a way to do this multi-threaded.

I found many solutions (Commandline pbzip2 or some C++ libraries) but all i found for java is this blog post:

https://plus.google.com/117421466255362255970/posts/3jfKVu325zh

It seems that i can't use it in my Java application.

Is there anything out there? What would you recommend? Or is there another faster solution with similar compression rates like bzip2 ?

Comment: I don't know if this is in your reach, but you could always try writing your own multi-threaded implementation of bzip2?

Comment: Hey Jesse, yeah that'd be swell, but that's sure out of my reach.

Comment: How about invoking http://compression.ca/pbzip2/ from within your Java application?

Comment: @reprogrammer yes, that would do the trick. i'd take this approach if there's no other solution

Comment: Turned it into an answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have multiple files, you can compress each file in a different thread. As your process is CPU bound, I suggest creating a fixed size thread pool i.e. an ExecutorService, and adding a task for each file to compress.

Note: if pbzip2 does what you want, I would call it from Java.  You might find it is fast for even one thread as the BZIP2 libraries I have seen for Java are natively implemented (unlike JAR, ZIP and GZIP)

Comment: I have multiple files, but it should result in one big tar.bz2 file - so it's just one file to be compressed

Comment: Compressed file are serial ie. based on what has happen before. I don't know how the other libraries get around this.  You could create a .bz2.tar file.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: Normaly you do first the *tar* to get compression crossing over more than one file to increase the compression ratio.

Comment: @MrSmith42 But if you do that you can't compression portions in parallel.  Looking at the docs, it appears that pbzip2 creates a tar file of compressed files.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: That's right. Parallelism can only be used within the bzip2 algorithm itself.

Answer (score 1):

If a parallel implementation of bzip2 in Java doesn't exit, you can resort to invoking [pbzip2](http://compression.ca/pbzip2) from within your Java application.

Answer (score 0):

Try at4j implementation of BZip2OutputStream. According to the manual it supports parallel compresion.
http://at4j.sourceforge.net/releases/current/pg/ch04.xhtml